# Rewrite a file in-place with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, io

It might depend on each OS and also be hardware-dependent, but is there a way in Python to **ask a write operation on a file to happen "in-place", i.e. *at the same place* of the original file**, i.e. if possible on the same sectors on disk?

Example: let's say `sensitivedata.raw`, a 4KB file has to be crypted:

```
with open('sensitivedata.raw', 'r+') as f:  # read write mode
    s = f.read()
    cipher = encryption_function(s)  # same exact length as input s
    f.seek(0)
    f.write(cipher)  # how to ask this write operation to overwrite the original bytes?
```

Example 2: replace a file by null-byte content of the same size, to avoid an undelete tool to recover it (of course, to do it properly we need several passes, with random data and not only null-bytes, but here it's just to give an idea)

```
with open('sensitivedata.raw', 'r+') as f:
    s = f.read()
    f.seek(0)
    f.write(len(s) * '\x00')  # totally inefficient but just to get the idea
os.remove('sensitivedata.raw')
```

PS: if it really depends a lot on OS, I'm primarily interested in the Windows case

---

Side-quesion: if it's not possible in the case of a SSD, does this mean that if you *once* in your life wrote sensitive data as plaintext on a SSD (example: a password in plaintext, a crypto private key, or anything else, etc.), then *there is no way to be sure* that this data is really erased? i.e. the only solution is to 100% wipe the disk and fill it many passes with random bytes? Is that correct?

Comment: Most file systems implement files as streams of bytes, so you can only modify a file in-place by replace `n` bytes with `n` bytes. You can't grow or contract a file without rewriting data.

Comment: @chepner Yes indeed, for this reason in my 2 examples, I replace `n` bytes by exactly `n` bytes.

Comment: Minor side-note: Encrypting data *should* make it a little bigger. Even if no IV is needed (most good schemes use one), and the key is always provided by user input, never stored, if you don't do store *some* extra data (HMAC, magic number, whatever) with the data, you have no programmatic way of knowing whether the decrypt was correct. You don't want the user to encrypt with `"password"`, then accidentally drop a letter on the decrypt side (say, entering `"pasword"`), and end up with complete garbage that can't be recovered unless they guess the typo and reencrypt, then decrypt correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's an impossible requirement to impose. While on most spinning disk drives, this will happen automatically (there's no reason to write the new data elsewhere when it could just overwrite the existing data directly), SSDs *can't* do this (when they claim to do so, they're lying to the OS).

SSDs can't rewrite blocks; they can only erase a block, or write to an empty block. The implementation of a "rewrite" is to write to a new block (reading from the original block to fill out the block if there isn't enough new data), then (eventually, cause it's relatively expensive) erase the old block to make it available for a future write.

**Update addressing side-question**: The only truly secure solution is to run your drive through a woodchipper, then crush the remains with a millstone. :-) Really, in most cases, the window of vulnerability on an SSD should be relatively short; erasing sectors is expensive, so even SSDs that don't honor `TRIM` typically do it in the background to ensure future (cheap) write operations aren't held up by (expensive) erase operations. This isn't really so bad when you think about it; sure, the data is visible for a period of time after you logically erased it. But it was visible for a period of time *before* you erased it too, so all this is doing is extending the window of vulnerability by (seconds, minutes, hours, days, depending on the drive); the mistake was in storing sensitive data to permanent storage in the first place; even with extreme (woodchipper+millstone) solutions, someone else could have snuck in and copied the data before you thought to encrypt/destroy it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there really no way with a SSD to get the "location"  of a block and ask to rewrite there later?

Comment: That would be something the disk driver handles; it's not typically something you have access to from Python.

Comment: @Basj: No way. The logical sectors are all you have access to, and the mapping from logical sectors to physical sectors is updated during these rewrites. The best you could do is finish your rewrite, then use some external utility to trigger an immediate `TRIM` (the command that says "go back and actually erase all those blocks you abandoned right now") on the drive itself. Even then, it's not fully guaranteed; historically, some SSDs have failed to actually implement on-demand `TRIM` (they just say "yup, I've done it", and perform the actual work when they feel like it).

Comment: @ShadowRanger Good to know. I edited the question at the end to add a linked side-question, your last comment seems to answer that it's correct. Do you confirm? If so, this is scary!

Comment: @Basj: Yeah, that's basically correct. In practice, over time, one assumes the drive will passively clear the logically empty, but physically written sectors just so it's not stuck scrambling to clear them the next time they're needed (as I said, it's one of the most expensive things the drive does; reads and writes are cheap by comparison). But there is no way to *guarantee* it if you can't trust `TRIM` to be honored. You can always buy drives known to honor it, but for software that you sell/distribute to others, you're stuck with whatever crap they're running on.